# Client stops working after sending message and server doesn't wait for mutliple data to come

Tags: c#, winforms, tcp, tcpclient, tcpserver

I've recently started learning about computer networks and decieded to try  TCP/IP server and client. They both work, but I'm having issues with sending mutliple data to the server. I've made it to look like a chat service between clients but the server accepts only one client and closes the connection after the data is sent and the client for some reason stops responding after sending data to server (I think the problem comes from the server and not the client itself), no error message, only on the server side when I force close the client.
This is how my server looks like...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //User can define port
            Console.WriteLine("open a port:");
            string userInputPort = Console.ReadLine();

            //listening for connections
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, Convert.ToInt32(userInputPort));
            listener.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("listening...");

            while (true)
            {
                //waiting for client to connect to server
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connection...");

                //when user connects to server, server will accept any request
                TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                Console.WriteLine("Client Accepted");

                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                StreamReader streamR = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
                StreamWriter streamW = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());

                while (true)
                {
                    if(client.Connected)
                    {
                        if (stream.CanRead)
                        {
                            //buffer
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                            stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            int recv = 0;
                            foreach (byte b in buffer)
                            {
                                if(b != 0)
                                {
                                    recv++;
                                }
                            }
                            string request = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, recv);
                            Console.WriteLine("request recived: " + request);
                            streamW.Flush();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is how the client looks like...

```
...
                try
                {
                    //try to connect
                    client = new TcpClient(textBoxIP.Text, Convert.ToInt32(textBoxPort.Text));  
                }
...
        static void sendMessage(string message, TcpClient client)
        {
            int byteCount = Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(message);
            byte[] sendData = new byte[byteCount];
            sendData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            stream.Write(sendData, 0, sendData.Length);

            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
            string respone = streamReader.ReadLine();

            stream.Close();
            client.Close();
        }
```

Like I said, I'm still learning about computer networking and any comment to this code will help!
Thank you

Comment: So when you debugged every major and line and state. What results did you get, where does program differ from your expectations? If you cant answer that, you haven't done enough to debug your code. You need to hold the facts when writing complex software, you need to be certain of how its running, guessing is going to end in failure and questions that wont be answered on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps if you give yourself some idea of what you're actually expecting from the code you're writing. It seems to me that you make a lot of automatic assumptions without actually making sure to put them in your code.

1. Your server can only ever at best accept a single client. Not one client *at a time*, but one *ever*. You never exit from your reading loop, so after the client disconnects, you end up in a wonderful infinite busy loop. Your intent was probably to serve another client when one disconnects, but that's not what you're doing.
2. You assume the server will send a response to the client. But you never actually send any response! For a client to read something, the server first must send something for the client to read.
3. You assume the string sent by the client will be zero-terminated, or that the target buffer for `Read` will be zeroed. If you want zero-termination, you have to send it yourself from the client - the `StreamWriter` *certainly* doesn't do that. Strings aren't zero-terminated as a *rule* - it's just one C-style way of representing strings in memory. You shouldn't assume anything about the contents of the buffer *beyond* what the return value from `Read` tells you was returned.

Those are issues with things you forgot to quite put in, presumably. Now to the incorrect assumptions on part of how TCP works. To keep clarity, I will tell the way it *is*, rather than the incorrect assumption.

1. A single write can result in multiple reads on the other side, and a single read can read data from multiple writes on the other side. TCP doesn't send (and receive) messages, it deals with streams. You need to add a messaging protocol on top of that if streams aren't good enough for you.
2. `Read` returns how many bytes were read. Use that to process the response, instead of looking for a zero. When `Read` returns a zero, it means the connection has been closed, and you should close your side as well. This is all that you need, instead of all the `while (true)`, `if (Connected)` and `if (CanRead)` - loop until `Read` returns zero. Process data you get as it gets to you.
3. The TCP stream is a bit trickier to work with than most streams; it behaves differently enough that using helpers like `StreamReader` is dangerous. You have to do the work yourself, or get a higher-abstraction library to work with networking. TCP is *very* low level.
4. You cannot rely on getting a response to a `Read`. TCP uses connections, but it doesn't do anything to keep the connection alive on its own, or notice when it is down - it was designed for a very different internet than today's, and it can happily survive interruptions of service for hours - as long as you don't try to *send* anything. If the client disconnects abruptly, the server might never know.

You should also make sure to clean up all the native resources properly - it really helps to use `using` whenever possible. .NET will clean up *eventually*, but for things like I/O, that's often dangerously late.

Answer (score 1):

```
                while (true)
                {
                    if(client.Connected)
                    {
                        if (stream.CanRead)
                        {
```

I don't see any code, that exits the outer while the loop if either `client.Connected` or `stream.CanRead` become false. So, when the client disconnects and they become false, it seems to me that the server just loops forever.

You should at least do all error handling (close all necessary streams) and break out of the loop.

As the next problem, you code can only have one client at a time. If the client is not actually closing the connection. I do not know for sure what the correct C# solution is, but i think it is spawning a separate thread for each connected client.